# Angular 2 - Lifecycle hooks for lazy loaded modules

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components, lifecycle

I am in the process of developing an application using lazy loaded Angular modules.

I have a simple question:

Is it possible to catch an event when a module is loaded?

For example OnInit. This link explains life cycle hooks but it is only for components: [Lifecycle hooks for components](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

I cant find any documentation that explains how to hook in for modules.

Does someone have an idea of how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: *my issue* - what is it? The question should have clear problem statement and preferably http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Modules don't have hooks. Components do. Including lazy-loaded ones.

Comment: A better question would involve the *context* - what is it that you're trying to *do* at a certain point in the module lifecycle? Otherwise it's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated my question. My code is a simple prototype to show if it is possible to catch an event when a module is loaded. So there is no context other than that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The constructor of the lazy loaded module should do that

```
@NgModule({...})
export class MyLazyModule {
  constructor(/* service injection here if required */) {
    console.log('lazy module loaded');
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn. A bit embarrassing that i did not see that one lol. It works as intended in my solution. I sometimes overthink solutions with angular. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two router events that you can use: `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd`. Also you can use `LoadChildrenCallback`. These might not do exactly what you want, but still can be helpful.

Also you can use the following trick:

```
@NgModule({
    imports        : [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule, ROUTING],
    providers      : [
        {provide: CustomService, useClass: CustomService},
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule implements OnInit
{
    //force CustomService service creation or inject other app service,
    // so use can use it to fire event or do smth.
    constructor(handler:CustomService)
    {
        console.log('handler', handler);
        handler.fire('module created');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I dont understand your reply (the code example). Is your point that modules can hook into lifecycle events like OnInit?

Comment: you don't have hooks, but you can detect when module instance is created and fire event.

Comment: @kemsky, wondering when this will be fired? During build stage?